# What is SHA256 OID used for?

Tags: c, hmac

I have found a great SSL library which is easy to understand (for me) and more importantly which is easy to take apart in order to just get the cryptographic primitives I want to use.

However there is one thing i do not understand:

```
//HMAC with SHA-256 OID (1.2.840.113549.2.9)
   58 const uint8_t HMAC_WITH_SHA256_OID[8] = {0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x02, 0x09};
```

This line [can be found here](http://www.oryx-embedded.com/doc/hmac_8c_source.html#l00058)
I have downloaded the complete source and demo's for cyclone but nothing seems to use this, it also makes no difference to speed or outcome when I remove it.

does anyone know what it is used for?

Comment: Its an object identifier for a cryptographic algorithm (guess which one?). OIDs are used in many places, generally for identification of algorithm usage. For example, a signature created by some source and validated by some client needs some form of identification (what is the algorithm used for the signature generation?). You can't just send a raw stream of bytes and say "check it!". The receiver needs to know *how*, and an OID is frequently used to communicate that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does anyone know what it is used for?

That is [`hmacWithSHA256`](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.2.9). Its used to identify the algorithm for system interconnect.

The other OIDs/HMACs in that arc are:

- MD2 - 2
- MD4 - 4
- MD5 - 5
- hmacWithSHA1 - 7
- hmacWithSHA224 - 8
- hmacWithSHA256 - 9
- hmacWithSHA384 - 10
- hmacWithSHA512 - 11